# Meta Search Engine/ Web Scraping in Android Studio/JAVA

Tags: c#, android, web-scraping, search-engine, meta-search

I want to create an application that basically search for something with some filters from various websites (I don't require to login to those third party websites so the data available is open to public) and show it on my application. I have a few questions:

**1. Is It Legal ?

 2. Is this web scraping or Meta Search Engine ?

 3. Can I get more information (any web links/articles) to know more
    about it ? How to achieve it technically ? One way I know that we can use the XPath technique to scrape but I am wondering if there are more ways.
I am NOT asking for the entire code. Just how to start / Any guidance?**

Thank You in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand how search engines work!
-Our so called search engines like google have special programs designed to mine out information from the web they are called "Spiders" what a spider does is basically scroll over all web pages within the search query and find matching information however that's a really complex thing to work on! it takes really good code and algorithm expertise to develop a spider for yourself. However if you can master that you'll be earning a smooth sum of money, but it's really rare unless you're a blatant genius!